# Azure - Send message to all other Roles and wait for response

Tags: azure, caching, cloud, azureservicebus, cache-invalidation

A really common pattern that I need in multi instance web applications is invalidating MemoryCaches over all instances - and waiting for a confirmation that this has been done. (Because a user might otherwise after a refresh suddenly see old data on another instance)

We can make this with a combination of:

- AzureServicebus,
- Sending message to a topic
- other instances send message back with ReplyTo to the original instance
- have a wait loop for waiting on the messages back,
- be aware of how many other instances are there in the first place.
- probably some timeout because what happens if an instance crashes in between?

I think working out all these little edge cases might be a lot of work - so before we reinvent the wheel - is there already a common pattern or library for this?

(of course one solution would be using a shared cache like Redis, but for some situations a memorycache is a lot faster)

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at Azure Durable Functions, e.g. [Fan-In/Fan-Out scenario](https://azure.github.io/azure-functions-durable-extension/articles/samples/cloud-backup.html). They use Azure Storage Queues underneath, but provide higher-level abstractions.

Note that Durable Functions are still in early preview (as of August 2017), so not suitable for production use yet.

Answer (score 2):

> I think working out all these little edge cases might be a lot of work - so before we reinvent the wheel - is there already a common pattern or library for this?

Indeed. This sounds like a candidate for a middleware framework such as [NServiceBus](http://particular.net) or [MassTransit](http://masstransit-project.com/MassTransit/?q=).

> AzureServicebus

Both [NServiceBus](https://docs.particular.net/transports/azure-service-bus/) and MassTransit support Azure Service Bus as the transport.

> Sending message to a topic

Both [NServiceBus](https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/messaging/publish-subscribe/) and [MassTransit](http://masstransit-project.com/MassTransit/understand/publishing.html) can `Publish` messages ([events](https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/messaging/messages-events-commands#event)) to topics.

> other instances send message back with ReplyTo to the original instance

Both [NServiceBus](https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/messaging/messages-events-commands#command) and [MassTransit](http://masstransit-project.com/MassTransit/usage/producing-messages.html) can send messages to specific destination. NServiceBus also can [`Reply`](https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/messaging/reply-to-a-message) to the originator of an incoming message using a [request/reply pattern](http://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/messaging/RequestReply.html).

> have a wait loop for waiting on the messages back

Both [NServiceBus](https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/sagas/) and [MassTransit](http://masstransit-project.com/MassTransit/advanced/sagas/) support [Sagas](https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2013/03/21/saga-implementation-patterns-variations/), also known as [Process Coordinator pattern](http://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/messaging/ProcessManager.html).

> be aware of how many other instances are there in the first place.

Not sure about this requirement. When you scale out, you're running with a competing consumer and shouldn't care about number of instances of an endpoint.

> probably some timeout because what happens if an instance crashes in between?

If you refer to retries and recovery, then both [NServiceBus](https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/recoverability/) and [MassTransit](http://masstransit-project.com/MassTransit/usage/retries.html) support retries.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Azure Redis cache pub/sub model to do this. 
1) Subscribe to Redis multiplexer

```
connectionMultiplexer.GetSubscriber().Subscribe(
                        "SubscribeChannelName",
                        (channel, message) => { 

invalidate cache here and publish the confirmation using below publish method
connectionMultiplexer.GetSubscriber().PublishAsync("PublishChannelName", "Cache invalidated for instance").Wait();
});
```

2) Publish the cache invalidation and subscribe for confirmation from instances

```
var connection = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect("redis connection string");
var redisSubscriber = connection.GetSubscriber();
redisSubscriber.Subscribe(
                        "PublishChannelName",
                        (channel, message) => {

// write logic to verify if all instances notified about cache invalidation.
});
redisSubscriber.PublishAsync("SubscribeChannelName","invalidate cache")).Wait();
```